# overriding the what function in std::exception in c++

Tags: c++, c++11, exception, overriding, virtual-functions

I'm trying to override the what function in order to print customized error messages of my own.

all messages have the same beginning and therefore I thought that it would be best if I could do the following :

```
class Exception : public std::exception
{
    public:
    virtual const char* what() const throw() noexcept
    {
        return ("A game related error has occurred: " +  "class name");
        //note : "class name" above is the error message I want to print 
        //depending on the situation, which can vary a lot(we have 8 different messages)
    }
};


//examples of "class name" /otherwise known by us as error messages:

class IllegalArgument : public Exception {};

class IllegalCell  : public Exception {};
```

my problem is the following :

I couldn't quite figure out how I can print a varying message depending on which error I receive
without making a special what function in each error class - meaning I had to add a what function to IllegalArgument,IllegalCell and every other error class, which is bad in my eyes because it's too many functions to uphold and keep updating overtime. is there anyway I can avoid that, and just be able to print a varying message in the main class - Exception?

Comment: Make sure the signature is correct for the version of C++ you are using:
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/exception/what (you now have both throw() and noxcept, only one is needed)

Comment: Just pass the class name to your `Exception` constructor and use it in `what()`. If you're fine with having potentially weird class names, you can use `typeid(*this).name()` to retrieve the name of the class.

Comment: the signature we're using is indeed correct, I'm using c++11.

Comment: Holt, can you explain a little more?

Comment: @Saleh See my answer.

Comment: @Holt what would happen if we return (m_) in what?

Comment: @Saleh `what()` returns a `const char*`, not a `std::string`, you cannot `return m_;` in `what()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the name of the class to `Exception` constructor and store the name:

```cpp
class Exception : public std::exception {
public:
    virtual const char *what() const noexcept {
        return m_.c_str();
    }

protected:
    Exception(std::string const& name) : m_{"A game related error has occurred: " + name} {}

private:
    std::string m_;
};

class IllegalArgument: public Exception {
public:
    IllegalArgument() : Exception("IllegalArgument") {}
};
```

You can write a macro to define your child exceptions if you don't want to bother writing the default constructor each time.

---

Another option if you are fine with having generated names, is to use `typeid()`, e.g.

```cpp
class Exception : public std::exception {
public:
    virtual const char *what() const noexcept {
        // you need a static here to maintain the buffer since you are returning a
        // const char*, not a string, and you cannot construct this string in the
        // constructor because typeid() will not work properly in the constructor
        //
        static const std::string s = 
            std::string("A game related error has occurred: ") + typeid(*this).name();
        return s.c_str();
    }
};

class IllegalArgument : public Exception { };
```

The name generated by `typeid(*this).name()` is not standard, e.g., wit gcc I get `15IllegalArgument`, so that's up to you.